# It worked in jquery 1.3.0 but it will not work on 1.10.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal is to onClick change the input and displayed price. The code below works in jquery 1.3.0 but not in 1.10.1. What am I missing? If there is a better way please let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("").click(update2);
});

function update2() {
    var Myprice = $("#price").val();
    $('#displayPrice').html('Price: ' + Myprice + '');
}
```

HTML markup -

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" class="item_price" value="$15.00">
</label>
<div id="displayPrice" name="displayPrice" class="form_total">Price: $25.00</div>
<div class="xsshirt">
    <input id="size5" class="product-attr-size" name="size" type="radio" value="XSmall" onClick="document.getElementById('price').value='$25.00'" />
    <label for="XSmall"></label>
</div>
<div class="sshirt">
    <input id="size1" class="product-attr-size" name="size" type="radio" value="Small" onClick="document.getElementById('price').value='$25.00'" />
    <label for="Small"></label>
</div>
<div class="mshirt">
    <input id="size2" class="product-attr-size" name="size" type="radio" value="Medium" onClick="document.getElementById('price').value='$25.00'" />
    <label for="Medium"></label>
</div>
<div class="lshirt">
    <input id="size3" class="product-attr-size" name="size" type="radio" value="Large" checked="checked" onClick="document.getElementById('price').value='$25.00'" />
    <label for="Large"></label>
</div>
<div class="xlshirt">
    <input id="size4" class="product-attr-size" name="size" type="radio" value="XLarge" onClick="document.getElementById('price').value='$30.00'" />
    <label for="XLarge"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Try the jQuery Migrate plugin.

Comment: on click of what? you're missing a selector here `$("").click(update2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of jQuery, `$("")` and `$()` returned `document`, therefore your current code was binding a click event to the document.

Simply update your selector to target the document.

```
$(document).click(...
```

or even better, have it target a parent element closer to the target element (whatever the target element is, surely you don't actually want to catch ALL click events on the document?)

Answer (score 4):

You should use $({some selector}) instead of $(""). You are not attaching a click handler to anything by using $("").

As others have said, using $("") on previous versions of jQuery defaulted the selector to document so it was the same as $(document). Either way, it is not a good practice to attach listeners to the document or the document body. Try attaching it to an element closer to the one that is being clicked (not the clicked elements themselves as this would mean you are multiplicating handlers that perform the same action instead of having only one).

In this particular case I would add a wrapper to the shirt items and attach a delegated event listener to it, like so:

```
<div id="shirts">
    <div class="xsshirt">
        <input id="size5" class="product-attr-size" name="size" type="radio" value="XSmall" onClick="document.getElementById('price').value='$25.00'" />
        <label for="XSmall"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="sshirt">
        <input id="size1" class="product-attr-size" name="size" type="radio" value="Small" onClick="document.getElementById('price').value='$25.00'" />
        <label for="Small"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="mshirt">
        <input id="size2" class="product-attr-size" name="size" type="radio" value="Medium" onClick="document.getElementById('price').value='$25.00'" />
        <label for="Medium"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="lshirt">
        <input id="size3" class="product-attr-size" name="size" type="radio" value="Large" checked="checked" onClick="document.getElementById('price').value='$25.00'" />
        <label for="Large"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="xlshirt">
        <input id="size4" class="product-attr-size" name="size" type="radio" value="XLarge" onClick="document.getElementById('price').value='$30.00'" />
        <label for="XLarge"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#shirts").on("click", ".product-attr-size", update2);
```

Comment: That is the crux of the problem. Before jQuery 1.4, `$()` or `$('')` returned the same as `$(document)`. jQuery 1.4 changed that to return an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("*").click(update2);
});

function update2() {
    var Myprice = $("#price").val();
    $('#displayPrice').html('Price: ' + Myprice + '');
}
```

Look at the selector `$("*")` when attaching the click event. Make sure you replace * with something more relevant like `$("input:radio[name=size]").click(update2);` so that the price changes when clicked on the radio button only.

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdCFp/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the behavior of $("") changed.
Try binding the click event to the body:

```
$("body").click(update2);
```

This way, clicking any element on the page will bubble up the DOM to the body.